# Stacking data by hours AmCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

Is it possible to stack data hourly ? I have only two columns: time and signal from trigger "trig = 1". So I need to stack all trigger signals on each hour. So on Y axis should be a number sum of all trigger signals in each hour. You can use this example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3ypB/943/).
Data looks like this:

```
[{"time":"15:15:00","trig":"1"},{"time":"15:45:00","trig":"1"},
{"time":"16:10:18","trig":"1"},{"time":"16:20:00","trig":"1"},
{"time":"17:30:00","trig":"1"},{"time":"17:50:00","trig":"1"},
{"time":"18:25:00","trig":"1"},{"time":"18:45:00","trig":"1"},
{"time":"19:05:00","trig":"1"},{"time":"19:40:00","trig":"1"},
{"time":"21:15:00","trig":"1"},{"time":"21:50:00","trig":"1"}]
```

And my JS:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
"type": "stock",
"dataSets": [{
"title": "triger",
  "fieldMappings": [{
    "fromField": "time",
    "toField": "time"
  }, {
    "fromField": "trig",
    "toField": "trig"
  }],  
  "compared": false,
  "categoryField": "time",
"dataLoader": {
"url": "values4.php",
    "format": "json",
    "showCurtain": true,
    "showErrors": true,
    "async": true,
    "reverse": true,
    "delimiter": ",",
    "useColumnNames": true
}
}],
"pathToImages": "images/",
"dataDateFormat": "JJ:NN:SS",
"categoryAxis": {
"parseDates": true
},
"panels": [{
    "legend": {},
    "stockGraphs": [{
        "id": "graph1",
        "valueField": "trig",
        "type": "column",
        "title": "MyGraph",
        "fillAlphas": 1
    }]
 }],
"periodSelector": {
"position": "top",
"dateFormat": "JJ:NN",
"inputFieldWidth": 150,
"periods": [ {
  "period": "hh",
  "count": 1,
  "label": "1 hour",
  "selected": true
}, {
  "period": "hh",
  "count": 2,
  "label": "2 hours"
}, {
  "period": "hh",
  "count": 5,
  "label": "5 hour"
}, {
  "period": "hh",
  "count": 12,
  "label": "12 hours"
}, {
  "period": "MAX",
  "label": "MAX"
} ]
},
"panelsSettings": {
"usePrefixes": true
},
"export": {
"enabled": true,
"position": "bottom-right"
},
"categoryAxesSettings": {
"maxSeries": 1,
"groupToPeriods": ["5ss"]
},

"periodSelector": {
"position": "top",
"inputFieldsEnabled": false,
"periods": [{
  "period": "HH",
  "count": 1,
  "label": "1 hour"
 }, {
  "period": "HH",
  "count": 12,
  "label": "12 hours"
 }, {
  "period": "MAX",
  "selected": true,
  "label": "MAX"
 }]
 },
 });
```

Comment: You can group by hour like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3ypB/945/), but I don't know how to sum values on Y axis... Can't you work on the source data array, before creating the chart?